# What is the TDS and Conductivity of Ice from freezer, when, it has turned liquid?

Tags: conductivity, ph

Condensation of water vapors makes it distilled. I was wondering if the Ice formed inside the freezer top chamber can be used as distilled water. I tried checking the resistance with multi-meter, could not get a better result. Has anyone tried this before? What will be the TDS and Conductivity of such water ?

It is the atmosphere air condensation and not Ice formed inside a tray filled of regular water.

What will be its pH?

Comment: Might want to change the title, there is no such thing as "liquid ice", those are different states of matter. For the rest of your question, it seems likely that it'll be pure, just thinking about the physics of it.

Comment: Yes, liked your point so changed the title.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's mostly not about Electrical Engineering, and even the part that is about EE (conductivity) is unanswerable because only you have access to your melted freezer ice.

Comment: Condensation of vapor doesn't make it distilled...it's the fact that impurities in solution aren't carried through to the vapor.  Boiling it purifies it, condensation just puts the pure water in liquid form again.  Freezing water just freezes the impurities (which in turn lower the freezing point) but they don't have anywhere to go.  Lightly salt some water, freeze it, and see if it tastes like salt.

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis matter of fact, you can concentrate your salty water by freezing it: due to gravity, there's a salt concentration gradient along the vertical axis, and the less salty water on top freezes first, thereby pushing still-liquid water out between the forming crystals. You typically end up with pretty drinkable water up top, and sole pretty far down. Iff you cool slowly enough, that is.

Comment: Not sure about the pH, but go scrape some ice from your freezer and taste it - blech - not pure at all. Have to boil liquid water into vapor, and condense that vapor, in a closed system to purify it. In an open system like a freezer, lots of other junk are getting in there too.

Comment: Makes sense, impurity can come in an open system.